# C++ initialization style

Tags: c++, visual-c++, initialization

While reading a book, I found out that C++ offers a variety of initialization style. Few of them were:-

```
//1
double d1 {2.3};

//2
double d3 = {2.4};
```

So it said that '=' is optional when we use curly braces. So I gave it a shot and surprisingly 2nd method was working fine while the 1st one resulted into an error.
I am using Visual Studios 2010. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Upgrade your IDE. Visual studio took a while to become C++11 conforming (which is where this initialization syntax appeared).

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess you wouldn't expect VS 2010 to be C++11 conforming :)  And yes, it's well past its sell-by date.

Comment: @PaulSanders - VS no. But the standard is finalized (and the drafts publicly available) months before publication. Amazingly, Clang and GCC often manage to look into the future.

Comment: @StoryTeller Wish I could.  And MS do seem to be [pulling their socks up](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/03/07/c-standards-conformance-from-microsoft/).

Comment: @PaulSanders - It would certainly make this profession easier. I'd like to see requirements change on a clairvoyant developer ;)

Comment: @StoryTeller Hmmm.  They'd probably just plain go mad, like [Douglas Adams' sentient lifts](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/685736-modern-elevators-are-strange-and-complex-entities-the-ancient-electric) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 introduced a number of new C++ constructs and the "brace" cases above are called *uniform initialization*. This feature wasn't fully implemented by Visual C++ until VS 2013.

> You should see [this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/visual-cpp-what-s-new-2003-through-2015) as well as the [C++ Code Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines).

VS 2010 only implemented a few C++0x draft features, such as `nullptr`, `static_assert`, `override` / `final`, `decltype`, the new `auto`, and a first implementation of lambda expressions and r-value references (aka move constructors and operators). It was far from C++11 conformant. VS 2015 Update 3 or VS 2017 is a much better choice for C++11/C++14 coding.

> See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2012/09/17/dual-use-coding-techniques-for-games-part-1/)